# How to bottom align a DIV within a variable size TD

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How can I bottom align an element (a div or a span) within a table cell that height is dynamically changed.

```
<tr><td>
<div>Top text</div>
<img src="#variableheight" style="float:right" />
<div style="vertical-align:bottom">bottom text</div>
</td></tr>
```

[image]

Red one is the `<td>` with `background-color`. I need the SO#... `<div>` to be bottom aligned with the `float:right` img.

Comment: You have tried `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it doesn't work. Also tried containing it within another `position: relative` element still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to "clear" the `float` applied to `img`:

```
.bottom{
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bottom">bottom text</div>
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/L0j6sohs/

Comment: No, this approach totally breaks the wrap down of top text.

Comment: You can update the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0j6sohs/) with the necessary code to show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code code **fixed position for the div**.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
#td-content {
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}
table{
border:2px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Top text</div>
            <img src="#variableheight" style="float:right" />
            <div id="td-content">bottom text</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note:

1. I have removed the in-line css
2. Give an id to the div - `td-content`
3. Included css class
4. Please remove the table border latter.

Comment: This didn't work. Just set the `bottom text` element at the bottom of the window, instead of bottom of the `td`

Comment: Please check the html code now. I have altered it so it appears at the bottom of td instead body.

Comment: the latest addition didn't quite work but was able to align the top of the "bottom text" div with the bottom of the image. So it was basically looked like not making the `img` float and keeping them as inline block elements.

Comment: I've uploaded the actual image of what it looks like with 2 div solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do cannot be done by setting vertical alignment. You will have to do it normal way.
Have two divisions, one for left and another for right. Left division will have texts (top and bottom) and right division will contain image. Now because image will adjust height, keep it as it is (i.e. static) but make left division absolute to match the boundaries of td. Only thing to keep in mind is the distance of left division from right boundary of `td` so that it will remain away from `img`.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mykyd5s6/3/)**

```css
td {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
}
img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
}
#tdl {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 55px;
}
#tdr {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="tdl">
                <div>Some text aligned on top and wraps down when it hits the image</div>
                <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">bottom text</div>
            </div>
            <div id="tdr">
                <img src="#variableheight"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When I set the img `float:right` it sets the top element to be where I need it to be and img exactly where it should be. The only thing I cannot do is to bottom align the bottom text and image's bottom.

Comment: It looks like it works in the code snippet window but it doesn't work in my actual work. I'm trying to upload the image of what it looks like now.

Comment: What thing is not working in your code. The code I provided is working not only in the above snippet but also in jsfiddle and my own computer. You should be missing something while you edited your code. Please have a look at the above code again and try to make your code work similarly @BrianHawk

Comment: The reason why your code works here and doesn't actually work in my real example because you explicitly specified a 200px td width, img width and height and tdl right margin so that the text actually wraps around when it hits the margin, not when it hits the image aligned right. My question was for variable width td and img. When I removed the widths and heights it doesnt work `td {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
img
{
    height: 150px;
}
#tdl {
    position: absolute;
}
#tdr {
    float: right;
}`

Comment: @BrianHawk This was the only thing I was thinking whether to tell you or not. (not wanted to make you even more confused). Actually it is the best approach in your case. But you should know atleast width or height in it. And if not then you will have to control it with javascript or its library. Or use another approach i.e. use table inside that td

Comment: Funny thing is that it looks so simple to do yet I couldn't do it for a long while. I've tried table approach and it only caused more problems than it solved. Each cell's height must be 100%ed and even then it didn't work. Maybe I should try HTML5 or CSS3 or whatever there is other than JS. Thanks for all you time and efforts

Comment: @BrianHawk Because the left division is absolute so `td` could not know about the width of left division. But you can control it with right division containing img (which you wanted to make img to control). But you can give `min-width` to left division by giving it in `margin-left` of right division because it is the actual controller.